# Connecting to SQL Server 2016 with Visual Studio - only SQLNACLI11?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016

As I am reentering world of database software programming, have strong CS and programming background but really no experience with SQL Server and MS database ecosystem and tools.

Have set up remote SQL Server, which was lately upgraded to SQL Server 2016. **Connecting using SSMS works fine, no problem.**

However, using Visual Studio 2017 Server Explorer tab/window to set up connection works only if choosen data provider is "**.NET Framework Data Provider for OLD DB**" which in turn gives me Connection String like this:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=server.example.com;User ID=user;Initial Catalog=Demodatabse1
```

And this works fine, everything OK. Can create DataSet, work with it, etc.

On the other hand, if I try to use "**.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server**" data provider, connection is created, testing of connection goes well, but when connection is created, if I expand node in Server Explorer window it will expand to first level, but it won't load tables, I get this:

```
Failed to retrieve data for this request.
Failed to connect to server (local).
Login failed for user 'user'.
```

Again, SSMS 17.1 if working fine. Have checked and rechecked everyting from [Troubleshoot Connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine).

Checked installed ODBC drivers on the client system where Visual Studio 2017 is, I have installed:

```
ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
SQL Server
SQL Server Native Client 11.0
```

If I remember correctly, data provider ".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server" was woring fine before the upgrade to SQL Server 2016. Should it work now? What's the catch?

Comment: does it help if you use SQLNCLI10.1 ?

Comment: Don't know. Don't think I have it installed, plus, this is older version?

Comment: Try using the actual server name instead of (local). Also, VS 2017 is missing the SSDT add-in as of last I checked (3 minutes ago).

Comment: I don't know how to see if it is installed, but I tried it myself at some point, and it worked. If it does not work, then just change it back.